# Triangulation of multiple 2d sections

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation

I have multiple 2d polygons built up from points in y and z direction, each of these "faces" are located at a cordinate x. I want to show this as a solid model and therefor need to triangulate the points between the sections.

This would be easy if the points were evenly distributed and there were equal amounts of points on each section. But that is not the case.
One section can have 4 points, and the next can have 32. Does anyone know of any algorithms or methods to do this? 
I attached a picture that shows how the cross sections can look.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6B91.jpg

Answer (score 3):

For the case of parallel slices, you can have a look at [Boissonnat, Geiger 1993](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/69/34/PDF/RR-1697.pdf) and for the general case, this paper with references to other works [Boissonnat, Memari. 2007](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/~pmemari/SGP07.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a transformation that develops the section points onto a plane, use a Delaunay triangulation to triangulate these points, and then envelop the triangles back into your co-ordinate system.  In the sample given, you could develop the points radially by taking the centre of gravity or mean coordinate on each section, and using the distance to this point and bearing to this point as your developed coordinates.  This is a method I've seen before to triangulate the inside of tunnels.